# Как получить полезную нагрузку POST запроса

Tags: php, python, curl, request, response

В браузере, на сайте при отправке формы с 1 полем 'code', генерируется второе поле csrf_token.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ни в Headers ни в Content его нет.
Как можно получить его средствами php или python?

Answer (score 0):

Для php так:

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo $postdata["csrf_token"];
```

Т.к у запроса тип контента `application/json`, то доступ к необработанным данным запроса получаем через чтение из потока `php://input`. Далее остается только преобразовать данные из json-формата в ассоциативный массив.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]